# Tesseract-OCR : Using Tess4j in spring mvc web application on linux environment

Tags: linux, spring, maven, tomcat, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract-ocr in my spring web application on linux environment(linux mint - ubuntu 14.04) using tomcat 7 server. But I am getting an error as :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': libtesseract.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:145)
com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:188)
com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:123)
com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:255)
com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:241)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:45)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:283)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:219)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:168)
net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:152)
```

I am using the following code:

```
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
String result = instance.doOCR(file);
```

I am using maven to provide the dependencies for tess4j as :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also,priorly I have successfully installed tesseract on my linux maching using command:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr.
```

Important thing to note is that I am able to run tesseract from command line arguments and also from a standalone java project using Tess4j. It gives me proper output in both cases.

But while running using the tomcat server, I get the above error. 
I have `libtesseract.so.3` file located at `/usr/lib`. But somehow, tomcat is not able to find tesseract installation path.

What I am not able to understand is while running it as a standalone application, it is running fine and is able to find tesseract files but while running from a web server, it is not able to find the tesseract files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a link called `libtesseract.so`; something like the following?

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ ln -sf libtesseract.so.3 libtesseract.so
```

It seems like the web app is looking for something called `libtesseract.so` which it is unable to find.

Also check and make sure that `/usr/lib` is included in the `PATH` environment variable (`$ echo $PATH`).

Comment: Thanks Manish, that solution was perfect and worked like a charm. But I was wondering why this problem did not occur when I was using tesseract as a standalone java application?

Comment: I can only guess that the standalone app and Tomcat are using different paths and that `libtesseract.so` is available to the standalone app. The Tomcat startup script does tinker around with the path, which is why this could have happened. See if can find multiple copies by running `find /usr -name libtesseract.so`.